# RStudio Rmd-file: Why is the green bar on the left still showing up after executing the code?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I executed R code from within an RMarkdown document. And a green bar is still showing up after the execution. Did something go wrong here?

[image: greenbar]

I searched the forums but could not find someone else having this "problem". But maybe I did not search for the right terms.

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong. The green bars indicate that the chunk ran successfully and they remain visible on completion.

Comment: @neilfws Okay. Thank you. But strangely enough the green bar on the left of the output is only happening to two code chunks. On all other chunks the green bar does not show up.

Comment: There are a few little "oddities" in the RStudio UI, I guess it's a work in progress.

Comment: Perhaps the green bar remains because you haven't saved the output of that command. Does the bar go away if you save the output to a variable (e.g. "prize_money_1")? (i.e. if the chunk only contains `prize_money <- races_n1 %>% filter(grepl(...`)

Comment: @jared_mamrot Tried that. Since the filtered data frame is saved to a variable the output won't be shown. But there is still a mini green bar at the end of the chunk (at  ```  ).